# Highcharts: category positioning to match with datetime columns

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a chart like this one in Highcharts (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrah/526/)):

[goal chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlo4a.png)

The problem is with the bottom categories. They are added as a second axis:

```
 {
  tickPositions: [1, 3, 4, 5, 10],
  categories: ['Preparation', 'Base 0', 'Base 1', 'Base 2', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
  gridLineWidth: '1',
  lineWidth: 1,
  tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
}
```

They must match with the correct date ranges which are specified by the daterange columns above.
But by adding categories as a second axis, it seems not to be possible to arrange them by datetime.

How is it done in Highcharts?

Thanks,
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories in Highcharts have the same width, so to achieve the wanted result I would use a different approach. I would use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to create rects and labels which will simulate axis:

```
var categories = [{
    name: 'Preparation',
    value: 4,
    color: 'red'
}, {
    name: 'Base1',
    value: 2,
    color: 'blue'
}, {
    name: 'Base2',
    value: 3,
    color: 'green'
}, {
    name: 'Base3',
    value: 1,
    color: 'orange'
}]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    chart: {
        marginBottom: 150,
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var index = 0,
                    points = this.series[0].points,
                    pointWidth = points[0].pointWidth,
                    x,
                    y = this.plotTop + this.plotSizeY + 10,
                    height = 10,
                    width;

                if (!this.additionalAxis) {
                    this.additionalAxis = [];
                } else {
                    Highcharts.each(this.additionalAxis, function(el) {
                        el.destroy();
                    });

                    this.additionalAxis.length = 0;
                }

                Highcharts.each(categories, function(category) {
                    x = points[index].plotX - pointWidth / 2;
                    width = points[index + category.value - 1].plotX - x + pointWidth / 2;
                    x += this.plotLeft;

                    this.additionalAxis.push(
                        this.renderer
                        .rect(x, y, width, height)
                        .attr({
                            fill: category.color
                        })
                        .add()
                    );

                    this.additionalAxis.push(
                        this.renderer
                        .text(category.name, x + width / 2, y + height * 2)
                        .attr({
                            align: 'center'
                        })
                        .add()
                    );

                    index += category.value;
                }, this);
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vupj253c/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Thank you very much, this is awesome! I have updated my fiddle to integrate your changes (see http://jsfiddle.net/bLrah/527/).
For the labels, can they be automatically rotated on small screens (like the xAxis labels)?

Comment: Hi Philipp Staudt, Yes, you can make `rotation` dependent on chart width, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/myn329zk/